# How to communicate to a Metatrader 4 Server in order to read data from it?

Tags: mt4

I need to access the data available for MT4 Investor account or, in general, talk to MT4 server in order to read some data.
Is it possible?
It should, but i can't figure out how to do it ( is there a specific protocol? Is it allowed? Is there a library out there? Etc. )

Answer (score 2):

There is an API, but is for Brokers and other similar organizations only. MetaQuotes doesn't provide us direct access to it, but checkout the other link as well.

Here check this out [MetaTrader 4 API](https://www.metatrader4.com/en/brokers/api)
and also check this out [MT4 Server API](https://mt4serverapi.com/)

This is directly from MT4 Server API website

> API can be provided in Web Socket & Rest API. API is hosted on MT4 Server, further wrapped and consumed as web service and DLL .net and C++ API. This API is much faster than using MT4 Terminal for Quote and Trade; provides the real time open, close position and many more.

Please note, I haven't used MT4 Server API, so don't know much information about it.